# Getting around private copy constructor/copy assignment C++

Tags: c++

I have an object which upon initialization is passed a large data structure:

```
class foo {
public: 
   foo(const BigData& data);

   command();

}
```

`BigData`'s copy constructor and copy assignment operator are private, and rightly so.

However, I need to change `class foo` so that `command()` has access to `BigData`. Passing `command(const BigData& data)` is prohibitively difficult given the structure of the program, so I want to do the following:

```
class foo {
public: 
   foo(const BigData& data);

   command();
private:
   BigData m_data;
}
```

But how can I initialize `m_data` without the copy constructor or copy assignment? I also do not like the idea of `std::move` on the `data`, because it needs to remain a valid object in the context of the caller.

*Note*: I have declared the member a reference (i.e. `const BigData& m_data`) but this does not compile under icpc:

```
error: foo provides no initializer for reference member "m_data"
```

I have used `foo(const BigData& data) : m_data(data)` as well as `foo(const BigData& data) { m_data = data; }`.

Comment: If you don't want to copy, then you may need to store a reference (or a pointer, if you want to allow for re-seating and the possibility of holding a nullptr.)

Comment: "how can I initialize m_data without the copy constructor or copy assignment?" - You can't. as written `BigData` is not copyable except by members and friends of `BigData`, which I assume `foo` is not one of (and it doesn't sound like you want a copy anyway). Use a const-reference and make sure the passed `BigData` lives at least as long as the `foo` instance does.

Comment: "I have declared the member a reference..." It needs to be `const` reference, because you are trying to initialize it from a `const` reference coming in.

Comment: It is a `const` reference.

Comment: You mistyped something. Show what your class looks like now, copied and pasted directly from the code you actually tried to compile.

Answer (score 3):

How about storing a reference?

```
class foo
{
public: 
   foo(const BigData& data) : m_data(data) {}
   command();
private:
   const BigData & m_data;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If `BigData` has no copy constructor and no assignment operator, the authors do not want you to make copies of it. However, you can make `const` references to it yourself, like this:

```
class foo {
public: 
   foo(const BigData& data) : m_data(data) {}
   command();
private:
   const BigData &m_data;
};
```

Now your `command()` member function has access to `BigData` that has been passed to `foo`'s constructor.

One important point to keep in mind is that the lifetime of the `BigData` object is not tied to the lifetime of the `foo` object. You need to make sure that when `foo::command()` runs, the same `BigData` that has been passed to `foo`'s constructor is around. Otherwise, your program would have undefined behavior due to a dangling reference.

Another alternative is to make your own class similar to `BigData`, and make a copy from their class into yours. This may be prohibitive in terms of the programming effort, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo {
public: 
 foo(const BigData& data);

 command();
private:
 const BigData& m_data;
}

// constructor
foo::foo(const BigData& data)
: m_data( data ) 
{
 // usual stuff
}
```